# How to set search filters in jqgrid everytime i open search dialog

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid advanced search in my project. Everything works fine. Now I have to display a default search condition on click of search button. Please tell me how can I achieve this. I have tried the below code in beforeShowSearch

```
var postdata = 
                {
                    filters: '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[' +
                            '{"field":"invdate","op":"gt","data":"2007-09-06"}]}'
                };
                grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
```

It dint work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to reset searching filters on every opening of advanced searching dialog you can't use `beforeShowSearch` callback in the case because the `postData.filters` will be read by searching dialog *before* calling of `beforeShowSearch`. What you can do is adding of your custom Searching button with respect of [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons) which looks exactly like the original search button and use `search: false` option of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) to have no standard button. Inside of `onClickButton` you can reset the `filters` property of `postData` before calling of [searchGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#calling_conventions).

Alternatively you can reset the value of `postData.filters` inside of `loadComplete` callback and use `recreateFilter: true` option of advanced searching to force creating of new filter on every opening of searching dialog.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DefaultSearchingFilter.htm) demonstrate the last approach. It defines first the variable

```js
var defFilter = '{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"invdate","op":"gt","data":"2007-09-06"}]}';
```

and use `loadComplete` for resetting the filter

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").filters = defFilter;
}
```